# Setting up gnome-keybindings in a Bash function

Tags: bash

I'm writing a Bash script to automate setting up keybindings for my Gnome desktop. Changing shortcuts for ones that already exist is no problem.

The problem is with custom keybindings. I can hard-code those commands and it will work perfectly, but I can not setup custom keybindings using a Bash function.

A hard-codded piece of script would be like this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/ name "vscode"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/ command "code"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/ binding "<Super>v"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/']"
```

and as I mentioned, this will work.

So I tried to write a Bash function for this:

```
# a function to create custom keybindings
# first arg: a number assigned to keybinding
# second arg: name of the keybinding
# third arg: command for the keybinding
# forth arg: the keyboard shortcut for the keybinding
function key {
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/ name $2
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/ command $3
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/ binding $4
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/']"
}
```

And I tried to use it as follows:

```
key 0 "poweroff" "poweroff" "<Shift><Super>s"
key 1 "reboot" "reboot" "<Shift><Super>r"
key 2 "keepassx" "keepassx" "<Super>k"
key 3 "calculator" "gnome-calculator" "<Super>c"
key 4 "vscode" "code" "<Super>v"
key 5 "toggle_touchpad" "/home/ali/p/os/scripts/gnome_toggle_touchpad.sh" "<Super>t"
```

None of keybindings above work, except the last one, `toggle_touchpad`.

I suspected that maybe `toggle_touchpad` works because I provided a full address for it instead of a command. So I created a simple script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
code
```

This Script works but when I put it in the keybinding script, it doesn't work:

```
key 4 "vscode" "/home/ali/p/os/scripts/code.sh" "<Super>v"
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my script but I think it has something to do with the last line of function since the configuration of the previous three lines appear in `dconf`:

Graphical `dconf` interface showing a setting related to a custom keybinding:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you're not quoting variables:

```
function key {
    gsettings set "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/" name "$2"
    gsettings set "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/" command "$3"
    gsettings set "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/" binding "$4"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom$1/']"
}
```

Comment: That's not the case! Thanks for you attention.